# Is it possible to join 2 django models with no references?

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

I want to make a join with 2 django models with no relationship, so there are no foregn keys.

```
class Person(models.Model):        
    id = models.IntegerField()
    name = models.CharField()


class Pilot(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField()
    vehicle = models.CharField()
```

How do I join Pilot and Person by "id"?

Comment: If a `Pilot` is a person I would strongly advise to implement `Pilot` as a subclass of `Person`, this will make a `OneToOneField` from the `id` of `Pilot` to the primary key of `Person`, and thus can do the JOINing in an effective way.

Comment: I cant change the database structure because I my work is developing the backend for a company with an established database.
Also the code I wrote is only an example.